# MotionLayout not rendered when set the Scene

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

have a nice day

I try to create Motion layout programmatically by extending it. Just add view to it and invoke the motion.

However, when i try to `setScene(...)` my layout is blank like no render process is happen.
Maybe i missing something?

Here is the code:

```
class SimpleMotionLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MotionLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var _simpleTransition: MotionScene.Transition? = null
    val simpleTransition: MotionScene.Transition?
        get() = _simpleTransition

    init {
        initDefaultConstraint(this)
        setDebugMode(DEBUG_SHOW_PATH and DEBUG_SHOW_PROGRESS)

        val motionScene = MotionScene(this)
        _simpleTransition = createTransition(motionScene)

        /**
         * The order matters here.
         * [MotionScene.addTransition] adds the transition to the scene while
         * [MotionScene.setTransition] sets the transition to be the current transition.
         */
        motionScene.addTransition(_simpleTransition)
        motionScene.setTransition(_simpleTransition)

        scene = motionScene
    }

    private fun initDefaultConstraint(motionLayout: ConstraintLayout) {
        // View
        val squareView = View(context).apply {
            id = R.id.default_button
            setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
        motionLayout.addView(
            squareView,
            LayoutParams(
                fromDp(context, 52),
                fromDp(context, 52)
            )
        )

        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(motionLayout)

        // Setup constraint set to TOP, LEFT to the Parent
        set.connect(
            squareView.id,
            TOP,
            PARENT_ID,
            TOP
        )
        set.connect(
            squareView.id,
            START,
            PARENT_ID,
            START
        )

        set.applyTo(motionLayout)
    }
}
```

When i remove the `scene = motionScene` line, the view is successfully appeared.

[image]

Thank you